# Sorting columns that contain letters or numbers in a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm just getting into JavaScript coding. I am trying to sort a table with four columns. The sort happens when one of four buttons are clicked on. Two contain letters and the other two contain numbers. Those with letters sort fine. Though, those with numbers do not sort correctly. I assume I need to alter my function resortData somehow. Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

```js
var sortBy = 3;

var database = [
  ['Ray', 'Bourque', '1518', '1506'],
  ['Johnny', 'Bucyk', '1436', '1339'],
  ['Patrice', 'Bergeron', '1294', '1040'],
  ['Phil', 'Esposito', '625', '1012'],
  ['Rick', 'Middleton', '881', '898'],
  ['Bobby', 'Orr', '631', '888'],
  ['Brad', 'Marchand', '947', '862'],
  ['Wayne', 'Cashman', '1,027', '793']
];

function resortData() {
  database.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a[sortBy].toLowerCase() <
      b[sortBy].toLowerCase()) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a[sortBy].toLowerCase() >
      b[sortBy].toLowerCase()) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });

  var htmlString = '' +
    '<center><table cellspacing="20">' +
    '<tr><th>First Name</th>' +
    '<th>Last Name</th>' +
    '<th>Games Played</th>' +
    '<th>Goals Scored</th>' +
    '</tr>';
  for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
    htmlString += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < database[i].length; j++) {
      htmlString += '<td>' +
        database[i][j] +
        '</td>';
    }
    htmlString += '</tr>';
  }
  htmlString += '</table></center>';
  document.getElementById('tableDisplay').innerHTML =
    htmlString;
}
resortData();

document.getElementById('sortLast')

document.getElementById('sortLast').onclick = function() {
  sortBy = 0;
  resortData();
};
document.getElementById('sortFirst').onclick = function() {
  sortBy = 1;
  resortData();
};
document.getElementById('sortGames').onclick = function() {
  sortBy = 2;
  resortData();
};
document.getElementById('sortGoals').onclick = function() {
  sortBy = 3;
  resortData();
};
```

```html
<button id="sortLast">Sort Last</button>
<button id="sortFirst">Sort First</button>
<button id="sortGames">Sort Games</button>
<button id="sortGoals">Sort Goals</button>

<div id="tableDisplay"></div>
```